# gson returns empty object for Spring Page interface in SpringBoot RestController

Tags: spring-boot, gson

I have a RestController in a SpringBoot application that returns a Page (from Spring Data).

i.e.

```
@GetMapping("/api/issues")
public Page<SomeClass> getIssues() {
```

I'm using Gson. But it always produces an empty json object in the response. Stepping through the gson code, it seems to be unable to determine the bound fields of the object that it is serializing. I'm guessing this is because it tries to determine this at startup time rather than runtime, at which point it doesn't know the implementation class (i.e. PageImpl).

If I modify the method signature to return a PageImpl, it works.

```
@GetMapping("/api/issues")
public PageImpl<SomeClass> getIssues() {
```

I can live with that but I'm wondering if there is something I can do to be able to continue to use the interface in my method signature.

SpringBoot 1.5.8.RELEASE

Gson 2.8.2

Comment: Are you creating (or can you create) the `GSON` instance yourself or is it something Spring does under the hood?

Comment: Spring can do it under the hood but in this case I've injected by own instance in order to add some TypeAdapters.

Comment: I wonder would `GSON` call `JsonSerializer<Page>` or `TypeAdapter<Page>` if you added one?